# Kotlin/Android - Only one ToggleButton can be checked

Tags: android, for-loop, button, kotlin, adapter

I have a group of ToogleButtons. Inside the `adapter` I got them in an array:

```
val groupToggleButtons = arrayOf( holder.one,
                    holder.two,
                    holder.three,
                    holder.four,
                    holder.five,
                    holder.six)
```

**So, in this group of six, only one can be checked. If I press the button `holder.two` and then the `holder.six`, the `holder.two` must be unchecked on time**. Get it?
I've tried the next logic, but without sucess... the findViewById doesn't work, of course (because is an adapter), but then I don't know what to do, tried a lot a logics... nothing did what I want. Here's the code:

```
groupToggleButtons.forEach {
    it.setOnCheckedChangeListener { v, isChecked ->
        val buttonId = v.id

        for (i in 0 until groupToggleButtons.size) {
            if (i != buttonId) {
                val buttonToOff = findViewById(i) as ToggleButton
                buttonToOff.isChecked = false
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter from the array all the buttons that are checked and uncheck them:

```
groupToggleButtons.forEach {
    it.setOnCheckedChangeListener { v, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked)
            groupToggleButtons.filter { it != v && it.isChecked }.forEach { it.isChecked = false }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to acheive.

```
for(toggle in groupToggleButtons) {
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener { v, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) groupToggleButtons.forEach {
            if (it != toggle) it.isChecked = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. Can you explain the logic with comments, please?

Comment: Basically it says: set a listener on each button in the list, so that when that button is checked all buttons in the list are unchecked _except that one_ i.e. `groupToggleButtons.forEach { if (it != toggle) it.isChecked = false  }`